# Scroll Bars - Changing the color of a singular overflowing div only (not the outer page scroll)

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, scrollbar

After having an excessive amount of goes at this I am looking for help.

I wish to have standard scrollbars on my website however a div within my cart I wish to change to be a red thumb and standard background color.

Here is what I am dealing with:

```css
#popup-cart .cart-items {
  scrollbar-color: red;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}

#popup-cart .cart-items::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#popup-cart .cart-items::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#popup-cart .cart-items::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}


/* IRRELEVANT CSS */

.popup-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#popup-cart {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 250;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: left!important;
}

#popup-cart.open {
  display: block;
}

.popup-cart-section .cart-inner {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(100% - 148px);
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% + 34px);
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 151;
}

#outer-close-cart {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.close-cart-contain {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  right: -25px;
  z-index: 152;
}

.close-cart-contain img {
  width: 100%;
}

.popup-cart-section .section-inner {
  height: 100%;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}

#popup-cart .cart-header {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

#popup-cart form {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 92px);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.cart-items {
  height: calc(100% - 142px);
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#popup-cart .cart-item {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DADADB;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#popup-cart .cart-product-image {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#popup-cart .cart-product-information {
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#popup-cart .cart-product-header * {
  text-align: left;
}

#popup-cart .cart-product-footer {
  z-index: 151;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#popup-cart .cart-product-price,
#popup-cart .cart-product-variant {
  color: #585CD3;
  margin: 0;
}

#popup-cart .cart-product-price-multiplier {
  width: 60px;
  color: #585CD3;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

input[type="number"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.number-input {
  border: 1px solid #585CD3;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.number-input button {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.number-input button:before,
.number-input button:after {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #585CD3;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.number-input button.plus:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}

.number-input input[type=number] {
  text-align: center;
}


/*
#popup-cart .cart-product-remove {
width: 40px;
padding: 5px;
margin-left: 20px;
}

#popup-cart .cart-remove-icon {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
*/

#popup-cart .box-link:hover~* {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#popup-cart .box-link:hover~* .cart-product-title {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#popup-cart .cart-footer {
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

#popup-cart .cart-subtotal {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: #E20437;
}

#popup-cart .cart-footer-note {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: left!important;
  text-transform: none;
}

#popup-cart .cart-actions {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#popup-cart .cart-view-cart-contain {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #585CD3;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #585CD3;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
  transition: all 0.7s;
}

#popup-cart .cart-view-cart-contain:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #585CD3;
  border: 1px solid #585CD3;
}

#popup-cart .cart-update {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  color: #0E0530;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #0E0530;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
  transition: all 0.7s;
}

#popup-cart .cart-update:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #0E0530;
  border: 1px solid #0E0530;
}

#popup-cart .cart-checkout {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #E20437;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #E20437;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
  transition: all 0.7s;
}

#popup-cart .cart-checkout:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #E20437;
  border: 1px solid #E20437;
}


/* END IRRELEVANT CSS */
```

```html
<div class="popup-container">
<div id="popup-cart " class="section popup-cart-section ">
 <a id="outer-close-cart " href="javascript:void(0) " class="box-link close-cart "></a>

 <div class="cart-inner ">

  <div class="close-cart-contain ">
   <a id="close-cart " href="javascript:void(0) " class="box-link close-cart "></a>
   <img class="cart-close-icon " src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/delete-red.png?3351 " alt="Close ">
  </div>

  <div class="section-inner "> 

   <div class="cart-header ">
    <h1 class="cart-header-title ">Your cart</h1>
    <img class="cart-header-icon " src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/cart-red.png?3351 " alt="Cart ">
   </div>

   <form action="/cart " method="post " novalidate>

    <div class="cart-items ">
     <div class="cart-item ">
      <a href="{{ item.url | within: collections.all }} " class="box-link "></a>
      <div class="cart-product-image " style="background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/cart-red.png?3351) ">
      </div>
      <div class="cart-product-information ">
       <div class="cart-product-header ">
        <h5 class="cart-product-title ">hello world</h5>
       </div>
       <div class="cart-product-footer ">
        <p class="cart-product-price ">0000</p>
        <div class="number-input ">
         <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector( 'input[type=number]').stepDown() " ></button>
         <input class="cart-product-price-multiplier " type="number " name="updates[] " id="updates_{{ item.key }} " value="{{ item.quantity }} " min="0 ">
         <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector( 'input[type=number]').stepUp() " class="plus "></button>
        </div>
        <p class="cart-product-variant ">000000
        </p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="cart-item ">
      <a href="{{ item.url | within: collections.all }} " class="box-link "></a>
      <div class="cart-product-image " style="background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/cart-red.png?3351) ">
      </div>
      <div class="cart-product-information ">
       <div class="cart-product-header ">
        <h5 class="cart-product-title ">hello world</h5>
       </div>
       <div class="cart-product-footer ">
        <p class="cart-product-price ">0000</p>
        <div class="number-input ">
         <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector( 'input[type=number]').stepDown() " ></button>
         <input class="cart-product-price-multiplier " type="number " name="updates[] " id="updates_{{ item.key }} " value="{{ item.quantity }} " min="0 ">
         <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector( 'input[type=number]').stepUp() " class="plus "></button>
        </div>
        <p class="cart-product-variant ">000000
        </p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="cart-item ">
      <a href="{{ item.url | within: collections.all }} " class="box-link "></a>
      <div class="cart-product-image " style="background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/cart-red.png?3351) ">
      </div>
      <div class="cart-product-information ">
       <div class="cart-product-header ">
        <h5 class="cart-product-title ">hello world</h5>
       </div>
       <div class="cart-product-footer ">
        <p class="cart-product-price ">0000</p>
        <div class="number-input ">
         <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector( 'input[type=number]').stepDown() " ></button>
         <input class="cart-product-price-multiplier " type="number " name="updates[] " id="updates_{{ item.key }} " value="{{ item.quantity }} " min="0 ">
         <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector( 'input[type=number]').stepUp() " class="plus "></button>
        </div>
        <p class="cart-product-variant ">000000
        </p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="cart-item ">
      <a href="{{ item.url | within: collections.all }} " class="box-link "></a>
      <div class="cart-product-image " style="background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/cart-red.png?3351) ">
      </div>
      <div class="cart-product-information ">
       <div class="cart-product-header ">
        <h5 class="cart-product-title ">hello world</h5>
       </div>
       <div class="cart-product-footer ">
        <p class="cart-product-price ">0000</p>
        <div class="number-input ">
         <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector( 'input[type=number]').stepDown() " ></button>
         <input class="cart-product-price-multiplier " type="number " name="updates[] " id="updates_{{ item.key }} " value="{{ item.quantity }} " min="0 ">
         <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector( 'input[type=number]').stepUp() " class="plus "></button>
        </div>
        <p class="cart-product-variant ">000000
        </p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="cart-item ">
      <a href="{{ item.url | within: collections.all }} " class="box-link "></a>
      <div class="cart-product-image " style="background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/cart-red.png?3351) ">
      </div>
      <div class="cart-product-information ">
       <div class="cart-product-header ">
        <h5 class="cart-product-title ">hello world</h5>
       </div>
       <div class="cart-product-footer ">
        <p class="cart-product-price ">0000</p>
        <div class="number-input ">
         <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector( 'input[type=number]').stepDown() " ></button>
         <input class="cart-product-price-multiplier " type="number " name="updates[] " id="updates_{{ item.key }} " value="{{ item.quantity }} " min="0 ">
         <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector( 'input[type=number]').stepUp() " class="plus "></button>
        </div>
        <p class="cart-product-variant ">000000
        </p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cart-footer ">
     <div class="cart-subtotal ">
      <div class="cart-subtotal-label ">SUBTOTAL&nbsp;</div><div class="cart-subtotal-price ">0000</div>
     </div>
     <div class="cart-footer-note ">Shipping &amp; taxes calculated at checkout</div>
     <div class="cart-actions ">
      <div class="cart-view-cart-contain ">
       <a href="/cart " class="box-link "></a>
       <div class="cart-view-cart ">View Cart</div>
      </div>
      <button class="cart-update " type="submit " name="update ">Update</button>
      <button class="cart-checkout " type="submit " name="checkout ">Checkout</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Not sure this snippet is working unfortunately, I have tried my best to strip it down. But the same question remains.

**How do I apply the scroll bar changes just to the class cart-items? That will work across the majority of browsers, chrome, firefox and safari being the only essential browser support**

**EDIT: - This code now works - No solution necessary**

Comment: Currently you have scroll on the cart-items class so I'm a little confused as to what you want. Did you want that particular div to scroll? because currently you have it set to scroll ( although if you just use auto it will create a scroll if the div expands beyond the expected height that you set

Comment: Hi Keith, that is the div I want the scroll to be on, that class has overflow scroll, overflowx hidden, and the scroll effects applied to it, yet the colour will not change?

Comment: what do you mean the color won't change? Having a scrollbar doesn't change the color of anything

Comment: I am applying styles to that boxes scroll bars though? Please can you help me apply a red colour to the thumb of the box .cart-items

Comment: Keith, I have managed to make this work, not too sure how to be honest...

Comment: Hey you made it work, good job!

Comment: Thanks Keith, 100% unsure as to how though xD